# 'unexpected call to method or property access' error in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I am loading few aspx pages into a layout page using jquery , It is not working in IE7
and I am getting the error

> unexpected call to method or property access

**The Layout page**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="layout.aspx.cs" Inherits="layout" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/> 
    <title></title>
    <script src="script/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="script/myScript.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <link href="style/theme.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
</head>
<body class="layout">
   <header class="header"></header>
   <section class="content"></section>
   <footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**myScript.js**

```
$(function(){
    $(".layout .header").load("header.aspx");
    $(".layout .footer").load("footer.aspx");
    $(".layout .content").load("pages/home.aspx");
});
```

**Header page**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="header.aspx.cs" Inherits="header" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   header
</body>
</html>
```

The rest of the pages are similar to header page. Any idea what has gone wrong?

PS: `load` works fine, so I doubt that is the one causing the issue

Comment: are the file paths correct? Which file does the error refer to?

Comment: might be because you are trying to load a complete html file, try `$(".layout .header").load("header.aspx body");`

Comment: @ArunPJohny not working

Comment: the same has to be done for other links also

Comment: @hime yes the paths are correct, The error refers to the layout page itself

Comment: @ArunPJohny :) I did that, ofcourse. that doesn't work

Comment: Just to be sure, this is only specific to IE7? Does it happen in IE9/10? And it works fine in Firefox/Chrome?

Comment: @JofryHS, yes it works well with FF and chrome,as for IE i haven't tested it in others except the one I have, IE7!

Comment: Just a wild thought, perhaps IE7 does not play well with `<section> <header> <footer>`, you know, being old and all. :D Try with `<div>`?

Comment: @JofryHS , yup that was the issue :D! Thanks, mind posting an answer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE7 is too old to understand `<section><header><footer>`.

Use `<div>` instead.